# Can you mix spring's security and rest api together?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot and I want to create a rest api for my back end, but I also like spring security's authentication system and I want t use it in my application without having to make my own restful api for that part of the code.

Is this doable and will it be better to do it this way rather than make everything as a rest api?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's very doable. Steps:

1. you have to configure spring security session management to stateless

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).and()
               .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
   ```

   }
2. configure an authentication entry point to return HTTP status instead of a view

   ```
   @Bean
   public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
       return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
           @Override
           public void commence(HttpServletRequest resq, HttpServletResponse resp, AuthenticationException arg2)
               throws IOException, ServletException {
               resp.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Secured URL Hit");
           }
       };
   }
   ```
3. Proceed with the usual authentication provider